# How to fix the random distribution in image while executing code number of times?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using matlab software and doing work related image processing on it. I have some confusion regarding it. The problem i am facing is below:
I took image and add some random valued impulse noise on it. In below way:

```
img=imread(a,'bmp');
ND=0.4; 
Narr = rand(size(img));
N = Narr;
    N(N>=ND)=0;
    N1 = N;
    N1 = N1(N1>0);
    Imn=min(N1(:));
    Imx=max(N1(:));
    N=(((N-Imn).*(255-0))./(Imx-Imn));
    img(Narr<ND) = N(Narr<ND);
    img;
Some code;
```

Every time i changed something in Some code section and runing it.It gives different impulse pixels values. I want to fixed my noise distribution while i am runing my code any number of times.
What should be best approach to do this?

Comment: I'm no expert on MATLAB, but `rand(size(img))` is generating a random number, which would explain why your noise is different each time.

Comment: I am adding random noise ... But once i added it. I do not want to change impulse noise intensity while I am executing it any number of time.

Comment: What to you mean by `impulse noise intensity`?

Answer (score 1):

Two options -

1. Generate the noise once, before you execute the rest of the code, and always use the same noise array.
2. Before generating the noise, fix the random seed by running, `rng(seed)` with some fixed value of `seed`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Matlab but in most programming languages you get random numbers from a random number function. They differ every time. If you want to get the same random numbers every time you have to use a seed value